# Erosion compotition rule $\left ( f \ominus g \right ) \ominus h = f \ominus \left (g \oplus h \right ) $

Tags: filters, computer-vision, non-linear, morphological-operations

I want to prove that erosion of a signal by a function $g$ followed by erosion with another function $h$ is equivalent to erosion of the signal by the dilation of the two functions [(Erosion property)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Properties_of_the_basic_operators):

$$\left ( f \ominus g  \right ) \ominus h = f \ominus \left (g \oplus h  \right ) $$

**My approach:**

By definition of erosion we get that: $$\left ( f \ominus g\right )(x) = ⋀_{y} f(x+y)-g(y)$$

So, we get that $$\left ( f \ominus g  \right ) \ominus h = ⋀_{y}\left ( ⋀_{z} f(x+y+z)-g(y)-h(z)\right )$$

Is my approach correct so far? And if yes, how do I go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphological Erosion is not associative as dilation. Much like addition is associative but not subtraction. Consider the following basic definitions first:$$(A \ominus B)^C = A^C \oplus \widetilde{B} \tag{1}$$
$$(A \oplus B)^C = A^C \ominus \widetilde{B} \tag{2}$$

where $\widetilde{B}$ is the reflection of kernel $B$ and $A^C$ is the compliment of image $A$, inverse of image $A$. Now let us evaluate the expression in the question:
$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = ((A\ominus B)^C \oplus \widetilde{C})^C \tag{using eq. 1}$$

$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = ((A^C\oplus \widetilde{B}) \oplus \widetilde{C})^C \tag{using eq. 1} $$

$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = (A^C \oplus (\widetilde{B} \oplus \widetilde{C}))^C \tag{since dilation is associative}$$

$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = A \ominus \widetilde{(\widetilde{B} \oplus \widetilde{C})} \tag{using eq. 2}$$

$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = A \ominus (B \oplus C) \tag{distributing the reflection}$$

Hope that answers the question

Comment: Thanks for your answer!However, in this case the dilation and erosion operators apply on sets and not on functions, where the definitions are slightly different as far as I am concerned. Could you adjust your answer so that it contains functions $f,g,h$ instead of sets $A,B,C$ , since I don't think I can just simply replace sets with functions.

Comment: Functions are nothing but sets, when you consider their range space or domain as a set of collection of points. For ex: if the range space of a function is A in $\mathbb{R}^N$, the complement set is $\mathbb{R}^N$ -A

Comment: In my case,functions represent grayscale images. Can I just replace $A,B,C$ with $f,g,h$ as simple as that: $A \rightarrow f$, $B \rightarrow g$ and $C \rightarrow h$ and be valid with these properties?

Comment: What I have described above is with references to images. That's why  I use the terms like reflection of kernel and inverse of Image. It is valid to do that

Comment: Yeah, you are right! So, that answers my question. However, do you have any idea how this could be proved by just using the standard definition of erosion between functions, as I wrote down in my question? Because that was the way I approached this problem and I am curious how we can solve it in this case (as an alternative solution).

Comment: Sure, so eroding an image A, by kernel B, followed by eroding this equivalent image by kernel C. Now you can see that whatever is left by this eroding operation will have to be equal to the total erosion caused by combined size of kernels B and C. This is the desired result on the right hand size. You can now write this out using the basic definitions. Also, $⋁$ is used to denote dilation, its in inverted V that denotes erosion.

Comment: Also, if you have a satisfactory answer to the question , its always good to click the check box so that users know that this question has an answer that's accepted by the questionee.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will correct the erosion symbol. I am just not very familiar with these symbols in Latex. Would it be easy for you to include this alternative solution with the right symbolism in your answer, so that I can be sure I get what u mean? Will accept the answer as well!

Comment: I think, this way of approaching this problem is a bit un intuitive (just my personal opinion), I find the way I presented is more mathematically tractable and usually that's how its proven in literature. Honestly, its not easy to think in that terms I feel(though i provided an "in talk" explanation in that terms in the comment above, as you also see with the question. Here I give you a link to a lecture, might be useful in terms of manipulating  these operations. I used this to study morphology myself, although long back http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MORSE/morph1.pdf

Comment: It's true that my way of approaching is a bit more un intuitive and I will keep your explanation which is simpler and easy to catch. However, just for better understanding, I would like to see the alternative solution in that terms (written in maths), if possible, since I still can't figure out how it works. So, if u have the time, please write down as a comment the explanation you provided "in talk" with mathematical symbols. It will be really helpful for a better spherical understanding. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I was reading morphology the last days and noticed that in fucntion notation the duality property is written as: $$ f \oplus g = -[(-f) \ominus g^s] $$. So, it seems that the equations must be written in a different way than above. Am I wrong?